# DurableOrchestrationClient - return a result object

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a DurableOrchestrationClient executing a a couple of Activity functions working on a ActivityMessage object - how to I get a handle on the updated ActivityMessage object in the starter function?

e.g.
Starter function:

```
ActivityMessage am = new ActivityMessage();
var orchestrationId = starter.StartNewAsync("O_DispatchExecutor", am);
```

...>

```
[FunctionName("O_DispatchExecutor")]
public static async Task<ActivityMessage> 
TaskExecutor([OrchestrationTrigger]DurableOrchestrationContext ctx, ILogger 
log)
{
int index = 0; // 
ActivityMessage input = ctx.GetInput<ActivityMessage>();
for (; index <= input.Rules.Count; index++) {
Rule r = input.Rules.ElementAt(index);
try
{
input = ctx.CallActivityAsync<ActivityMessage>(r.Name, input));
...
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't directly view the changes made to your ActivityMessage object from the reference in your starter function. However, there are workarounds.

[Per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-perf-and-scale#internal-queue-triggers), "Orchestrator functions and activity functions are both triggered by internal queues in the function app's task hub." These queue messages include the function's input, which is serialized/deserialized to/from JSON on enqueue/dequeue, respectively. As a result, you lose the object reference, so it's effectively passed by value.

If you only want to view the updated ActivityMessage **once the orchestration completes,** return your ActivityMessage at the end of your orchestration. Monitor your orchestration's status in your starter function using [DurableOrchestrationClient.CheckStatusAsync.](https://azure.github.io/azure-functions-durable-extension/api/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.DurableOrchestrationClient.html#Microsoft_Azure_WebJobs_DurableOrchestrationClient_GetStatusAsync_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_) Once the orchestration is complete, retrieve the updated activity message from the [DurableOrchestrationStatus.Output](https://azure.github.io/azure-functions-durable-extension/api/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.DurableOrchestrationStatus.html#Microsoft_Azure_WebJobs_DurableOrchestrationStatus_Output) property.

If you want to view updates to the ActivityMessage **as the orchestration progresses,** you'll want to additionally use [DurableOrchestrationContext.SetCustomStatus](https://azure.github.io/azure-functions-durable-extension/api/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.DurableOrchestrationContext.html#Microsoft_Azure_WebJobs_DurableOrchestrationContext_SetCustomStatus_System_Object_) to output your ActivityMessage object to the [DurableOrchestrationContext.CustomStatus](https://azure.github.io/azure-functions-durable-extension/api/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.DurableOrchestrationStatus.html#Microsoft_Azure_WebJobs_DurableOrchestrationStatus_CustomStatus) property as it goes through updates.